# Range control input event not firing

Tags: jquery

I have written the following code with range slider. The change event is not firing.
I am not sure- where am I going wrong. The code is here.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1TE5DRCNRYC

Can somebody please advise?

Comment: Looks like you didn't include jQuery.

Comment: The <script> tag at the bottom of the code should do it. Or am I mistaken.?

Comment: You are mistaken.

Comment: I understood my mistake here. Sorry I did not get your comment at the first reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bassxzero  said in his comment you only miss the script tag that includes jquery. See the snippet below

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {$(document).on('input', '.slider', function() {alert( $(this).val());});});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">      
  <div><input type="range" min="1" max=100 value=50 class="slider" id="SpeedRange" /></div>
 </div>
```